# Change scrollviewer margin on button click c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, margin, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer with a standard margin(0,0,0,0). If I click on the button the margin for the scrollviewer needs to be margin(0,0,0,90). How can I do this in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 YourScroller.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,90);
```

On your button click

Answer (score 0):

I assume mainscrollviewer is your scrollviewer x:name

```
//Button click
 private void ButtonClick_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainscrollviewer.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 90);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button click set it programatically:

```
 ScrollViewer.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 90);
```